# Blank screen Cross compiling program QT5 Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, qt5, raspbian

i am doing a QT5 program wich has many assets and QMLS inside a QRC file (Total size of the program is 9 MB). I am cross compiling it in PC and then deploying it in Rpi.

But when i load it via RC.LOCAL in Rpi it shows a blank screen for about 4 seconds and then it loads my program. When i compile it for GNU/Linux, blank screen is not present.

What am i doing wrong? I think i have diferent versions of QT in Pc and in Rpi but the program works fine.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably loading resources, decoding png/jpg, interpreting QML and JavaScript etc...? You can use some logs to find that out.

Comment: Hi Luca.What logs are you talking? Thanks.